# Magento 1.9 - Media.phtml content not loading in my configurable products view page

Tags: php, css, magento, media, configurable-product

I have recently been learning the ways of magento, and up until two days ago it was all going great, but then I started learning about different product types .eg Simple, Bundle, Configurable. So anyway i needed to create a configurable product for a plain t-shirt, which had an option for colour and size. I added the image as i would any other product and made sure it was in-stock and done everything i would have done with a simple product, assigned the simple products and everything seemed fine. So i went on to my front end and it shows fine in the category page which its in but when i go to the actual viewing page for the product the Media.phtml file seems to be missing. The main image isn't there and inside the product-img-box div there seems to be nothing there (where my media loads for every other product).

Any help would be appreciated, i have searched everywhere for some sort of answer but haven't found a thing.

Thanks in advance, Josh.

Below is the code of my product/view.phtml page:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post"         id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-shop">
            <div class="product-name">
                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            </div>

            <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>



            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Overview') ?></h2>
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>

        </div>

        <div class="product-img-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
                <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
        <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
            <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
            <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $html; ?>
        </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the code of my product/view/media.phtml page:

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if ($_product->getImage() != 'no_selection' && $_product->getImage()): ?>

    <?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName();?>" onClick="$('image').src = this.href; return false;"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?><div class="product-image product-image-zoom">
    <?php
        $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');
    });
//]]>
</script>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) ?>', 'gallery', 'width=300,height=300,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="product-image">
    <?php
        $_img = '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(265).'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Below is where my catalog.xml loads in media.phtml:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Set block and html hints on via admin.

Step 2 : Clear cookies.

Step 3 : Refresh page and you will find block name and .phtml associated with that block.

This will lead you to debug .phtml and block code that should have rendered images as expected.

Now in case this does not solve provide what block and .phtml were called and paste those two files.

Comment: Just turned path hints on and media.phtml isnt being loaded! I haven't got a clue what is going on as it loads for every other product type.

Comment: in that case you need to check the Block and .phtml where you want specific html and proceed.